# Implementing your own optimistic locking SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, locking

I have seen a data model that implemented an optimistic locking mechanism of their own. What would be the advantages and disadvantages of implementing an optimistic locking mechanism of its own? Performance? Perhaps avoidance of deadlocking?

Comment: I'd recommend http://dba.stackexchange.com for this question but as a primer have you read BOL? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175519(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Considering the number of engineers that came up with the native locking structure... I have to admit I doubt rolling your own could come up with much of an advantage outside of a very specific circumstance.

Comment: My intention of asking this question was so that this information would be available and easily understandable for non-SQL person like me.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Martin. I am more interested in the second part of the question so I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean on the database or in the Object Relational Mapping (ORM) system.  There are many reasons at an application level that you may want to synchronise above database locks if you have some complex logic to implement, but these all inherently rely on the database's guarantees on it's transactional performance.

Could you give us some more info about what you need to know.